# Advice on how to accomplish background scrolling in all directions

Tags: javascript, css, pixi.js

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to begin creating an effect like (https://howifight.53.com) where the background is scrollable/draggable in all directions.

I know the technology behind this is pixi.js however, I can't seem to dig out how this effect is achieved. Any pointers in a good direction would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set up the page and styles.

You need a containing element to contain the HTML you're moving around (using `overflow:hidden`). Then you need an element within that to actually move around with JavaScript.

Then you need to implement some drag/drop functionality. Capture `mousedown`, then capture `mousemove` and update on each `requestAnimationFrame`, then stop dragging with `mouseup` is triggered.

That's a very basic overview, but I've mocked up an example for you to look at: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfpzojej/1/). Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: This helps illustrate the concept for sure. Thank you for the link to a fiddle.